# Manage responses of hastily aborted requests

Tags: node.js, http, request, fetch

My problem is this:

1. I have a React Native app that requests data to the backend.
2. If backend takes longer than x seconds, the app aborts the request (made with fetch()) and tries to make another one.
3. That abortion was hastily, because the backend was just taking a longer time to process it.
4. The backend is made idempotent so new requests don't actually matter.
5. The backend finished processing the initial request, and now it wants to return the value, but that request was aborted by the client.

How should I deal with this?
I can't just abandon the abortion logic because it's not my app, but I can make simple fixes and improve logic on it. Also, I can do whatever it takes in the backend.

Comment: Not sure what are the other possible options here apart from 1) Increasing timeout at UI 2) Improving backend response/processing time to return result within the UI time limit.

Comment: Couldn't I overwrite the "res" object in the backend when a new request arrives?

Comment: That might not work well in every case, actually

Comment: Not sure if these are the only options though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by saving the express.Response objects alongside it's requests. Whenever a new, duplicate, request arrives I just replace the response object in an array, so that I always have a way to respond the app.